# Cannot type upper-case 'q' with shift

Tags: windows, key-binding

I have a weird problem here. I am unable to type an upper-case 'q' while using the shift key. Hitting the 'q' key by itself works fine. I am having this problem with both the left and right shift key. I don't recall having the key bound to anything in Windows.

I've tested the key in Ubuntu and it works flawlessly. I've also tested it with a USB keyboard and that too did not work.

Comment: What language does the operating system think your keyboard is for?

Comment: @James I'm using the US layout.